# RecyclerView in fragment(bottomNavigationView) doesn't shown up when reselected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I have bottomNavigationView with 3 menus. Middle item is selected by default when app starts.
Middle fragment contains a recycler view which fetches data from sharesPreferences.
But when I select different menu and again select middle menu(middle fragment), the recylerview from middle fragment just disappers...
Anyone know what could be the reason?

**Created fragments**

```java
homeFragment = new HomeFragment(); //(middle fragment contains recycler view)
appSettingFragment = new AppSettingFragment();
infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
```

**Changing fragments**

```java
//this method is used for changing first and last fragment
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.settings:
                    btnAdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24);
                    addvis = false;
                    openFragment(appSettingFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.info:
                    btnAdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24);
                    addvis = false;
                    openFragment(infoFragment);
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        });
// this is used for middle fragment
 btnAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (addvis) {
                startCreateFormActivity("Untitled Form");

            } else {
                addvis = true;
                btnAdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_24);
                bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
                //homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                openFragment(homeFragment);
            }
        });
    }
```

```java
public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code? How do you switch between fragments and Fragment where the RecyclerView is

Comment: I have added the snippets

Comment: I think you need to add a switch branch for the middle item inside `bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: actually its bottomnav with FAB so on fab click i am adding middle fragment

Comment: do you really go to the middle fragment .. do you go to the `else` branch ? as you set `addvis = false;` in `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Maybe try with onResume in HomeFragment to refresh RecyclerView or adapter. It probably didn't disappear it's just something with data. I can't tell like this since it would be nice of you to provide the HomeFragment code.